# Error in implementation of interface between activity and view

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view, interface

I'm trying to get in my `MyActivity` an `int` from a View `MyView`. In my activity I have the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyView.GetCallBack {

    final MyActivity context = this;
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_act);

        task = new myTask();
        task.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPercentageReceived(int msg){
        // you have got your msg here.
    }

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            LinearLayout surface = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
            surface.addView(new MyView(getApplicationContext()));
            surface.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

    }
```

Now `MyView` contains the following code:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    final MyView context = this;     
    private GetCallBack callback;
    // Constructor
    public PlacingBoxView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        callback = (GetCallBack) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        dataPercentage(Percentage);
    }

    public void dataPercentage(int Percentage){
        callback.onPercentageReceived(Percentage);
    }


    public interface GetCallBack{
        void onPercentageReceived(int msg);
    }
```

I can compile the code without problems, but in the LogCat I get the following mistake:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.ex, PID: 8035
>                                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to com.example.ex.myView$GetCallBack
>                                                                                     at com.example.ex.myView.(myView.java:49)

I know the error is related with the Context, but I still haven't found out a way to correct it,

Any idea will be really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented the `interface` in `myActivity` but you are passing application context. That's why you are getting `ClassCastException`. Pass `myActivity.this`, so try like this:

```
surface.addView(new MyView(MyActivity.this);
```

Comment: changed the Capitals ;)

Comment: `myView` should also be changed to `MyView`.